# Word VBA: Table caption

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm dealing with a little problem using VBA in MS Word2003:

I have created a table and now I want to give it a caption, also with VBA...
Do you have any idea how to do that?

Would be great if you could help me a little bit further!
Greets, poeschlorn

@Edit: The word i was searching for was "caption" ;-)

Comment: Could you post an image?

Comment: Somethinglike inserting a field {TOC \f T \h \z \c "Tab"} _??

Comment: Sry guys, I didn't know how to explain what I wanted ;-) In fact, "caption" is the thing I was searching for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [InsertCaption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa212219%28office.11%29.aspx) method should do what you want.

Example from the link above:

```
ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Range.InsertCaption _
Label:=wdCaptionTable, _
Position:=wdCaptionPositionBelow
```

Comment: Ha! I didn't realize he wanted a caption. Good one.